# How can I install an android app to the emulator?

Tags: android

When using the `adb install MyTestApp.apk` command I get:

```
Can't find MyTestApp.apk to install
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Seems that the APK is not in the directory it should be or it is not named properly.

Comment: It is in the same directory - platform-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three different directories:

1. Current directory (it is shown as invitation parameter if you're working with ubuntu)
2. Directory where your MyTestApp.apk is situated.
3. Directory where adb command executable is situated (for instance, platform-tools).

In general you have to run the command `adb install` in the following way:

```
/path_to_the_3_dir/adb install /path_to_2_dir/MyTestApp.apk
```

So as `/path_to_the_3_dir/` is included into PATH variable you do not need to specify the whole path. You can simply call `adb install`.

To make things easier you can change your current directory to the directory where your apk file located (using `cd` command) and call simply `adb install MyTestApp.apk`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the APK you want to install isn't in your current directory? Try `adb install ./another/directory/MyTestApp.apk`